# Bind a model property to mdb-checkbox

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular12

I have an `mdb-checkbox` I want to bind to a field in my `member` component property named `questionAskedOnMyTags`.

So here's what I got:

```
export interface Member {    
    questionAskedOnMyTags: boolean;
...


export class MemberEditComponent implements OnInit {
  member: Member;
```

And the checkbox:

```
<mdb-checkbox [(ngModel)]='member.questionAskedOnMyTags' [default]="true" name='questionAskedOnMyTags'>A question is asked according to my tags</mdb-checkbox>
```

This gives the following error:

```
core.js:6498 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'questionAskedOnMyTags'
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'questionAskedOnMyTags'
```

I realise it can't bind the value, but I don't understand what's the correct way to bind it.